# The minimum value of $x^8 – 8x^6 + 19x^4 – 12x^3 + 14x^2 – 8x + 9$ is

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, maxima-minima, elementary-functions

The minimum value of $$f(x)=x^8 – 8x^6 + 19x^4 – 12x^3 + 14x^2 – 8x + 9$$ is

(a)-1

(b)9

(c)6

(d)1

Apart from trying to obtain $1$, which in this case is simple and $f(2)=1$ is there a standard method to approach such problems.

Please keep in mind that this is an objective question in one of the competitive exam and you get around 5 mins to solve it.

Also this is asked in elementary section, so only knowledge of basic calculus and polynomials is assumed.

Comment: Which exam is this from?

Comment: Do we know that one of the answers must be true?  Is it the word of God?  Take the first and second derivative and see which of those answers satisfy f'(x) = 0 and f''(x)> 0.  Or you could solve all 7 solutions of f'(x) but as that is a seven degree polynomial there is no guarentee it will be easy to do.

Comment: Yes it falls in the category of 'exactly one of the following options are correct'  questions

Comment: @fleablood I thought at that but the problem is you are only given candidates minimum value and not candidates minimizers so you would have to invert f for all the proposed choices.

Comment: You could however try to show that $f(x)>0$ for every $x$ and find $z$ such that $f(z)=1$ which is the first to start with

Comment: @Ovi its from indian statistical lnstitutes'   entrance exam for undergraduates

Comment: It seems to me that you should be able to write this expression in the form $(x^4-ax^2)^2+(bx^2-cx)^2+(dx-e)^2$ for some real coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$.

Comment: Wait!  *NONE* of them are the minimum value as none of them have derivative equal to zero.  Do you mean which of the 4 options are the least value of all.  Then just do them.

Comment: @fleablood you should maybe read my comment more carefully

Comment: The right value (missing) is $2$, at $2$ the second derivative is positive ($540$). There is an inflection at $1$, there the first derivative is $20$.

Comment: To fleablood and zoli: the proposed answers are minimal values and not minimizers!

Comment: Then $1$ is the correct answer. At $2$ the derivative is zero, the second derivative is positive, and the value of the function is $1$.

Answer (score 4):

This one is a bit tailor-made, I'm afraid.  The start of the polynomial naturally inclines to a perfect square trinomial (something that would obviously help in determining a minimum), and conveniently, it all falls out from there.

\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^8-8x^6+19x^4-12x^3+14x^2-8x+9 \\
     & = x^8-8x^6+16x^4 \\
     & \phantom{= x^8-8x^6\,\,}+\phantom{1}3x^4-12x^3+12x^2 \\
     & \phantom{= x^8-8x^6+19x^4-12x^3\,\,}+\phantom{1}2x^2-8x+8 \\
     & \phantom{= x^8-8x^6+19x^4-12x^3+14x^2-8x\,\,}+1
\end{align}

which allows us to rewrite $f(x)$ as

$$
f(x) = x^4(x^2-4)^2 + 3x^2(x-2)^2 + 2(x-2)^2 + 1
$$

The first three terms are clearly non-negative, and each reaches their minimum of $0$ at $x = 2$ (the first term also has a minimum at $x = -2$).  Thus, the minimum of $f(x)$ must be $1$.

This can't really be generalized.  (I mean, you can apply the approach generally, but it won't generally give you such a convenient result.)  I'm not sure I would have looked for this decomposition of $f(x)$ except for the presence of the question.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail please? When you say "The polynomial naturally inclines to a perfect square trinomial" what do you mean? In my mind a perfect square trinomial is $(ax^n+bx^m+cx^p)^2$, which isn't what you've done. Also, what made you think to look for factoring as $(x-2)^2$ instead of (for example) $(x^2-1)^2$?

Comment: @Ovi: I would interpret "perfect square trinomial" as a trinomial that is a perfect square, not the square of a trinomial.  (See [here](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/Factoring/FCPerfSqTri.html), for instance.)  I mean that I saw $f(x)$ begin $x^8-8x^6+\cdots$, and I thought, what would complete that square?  That would be $16x^4$.  So let's take that out, and continue with the remainder and see what we get.  (After all, if we take out a perfect square, $f(x)$ must be lower-bounded by the remainder.)  Then I did the same with what was left, and again, and was finally left with just $1$.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, that's indeed the common usage of the term "perfect square trinomial". Thanks for the reply, now I see your insight.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know that it counts as a heuristic, but if one *assumes* that the minimum is attained for an integer value of $x$, then either of the following observations leads to a plausible guess:

- the only integer root of $f'(x)=0$ is $x=2\,$, which suggest that the answer is $f(2)=1$;
- the only equations $f(x)=y \in \{-1,9,6,1\}$ with integer roots $x$ are in cases **(b)** and **(d)**, which suggests that the answer is the lowest of the two i.e. **(d)**.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c,d,e,k\in\Bbb R$,

$$(x^4-ax^2)^2+(bx^2-cx)^2+(dx-e)^2+k=\\ x^8- 2 a x^6+(a^2+ b^2) x^4 - 2 b c x^3 + (c^2 + d^2) x^2 - 2 d e x+e^2+k$$
By identification we easily obtain
$$a=4 \implies b = \sqrt{3} \implies c=\frac{6}{\sqrt{3}} \implies d= \sqrt{2} \implies e= \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \implies k=1$$

this implies that
$$x^8 – 8x^6 + 19x^4 – 12x^3 + 14x^2 – 8x + 9 = \\ \big(x^4-4x^2\big)^2+\Big(\sqrt{3}x^2-\frac{6}{\sqrt{3}}x\Big)^2+\Big(\sqrt{2}x-\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^2+1 \\ 
= \big(x^2(x^2-4)\big)^2+3\big(x(x-2)\big)^2+2\big(x-2\big)^2+1>0 $$
Hence, $-1$ can not be the minimal value.
As you have already noticed, it is easy to observe that $f(2)=1$ and since you know that exactly one answer is correct (see comments under OP), it must be the answer (d).

Comment: And I really believe that if you come up with the idea of writing in the form as in the first line, the rest is totally doable in 5 min with pencil and paper (likely even less).

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^8 – 8x^6 + 19x^4 – 12x^3 + 14x^2 – 8x + 9$

$= x^4(x^4 - 8x^2 + 16) +19x^4 - 16x^4 - 12 x^3 + 14x^2 - 8x + 9$

$= x^4(x^2 - 4)^2 + 3x^2(x^2 - 4x + 4) + 14x^2 -12x^2 - 8x + 9$

$= x^4(x^2 - 4)^2 + 3x^2(x - 2)^2 + 2(x^2 - 4x + 4) + 1$

$= (x - 2)^2(x^4(x+2) + 3x^2 +2) + 1 \ge 1$ with equality holding iff $x = 2$.

Comment: It asks about the minimum value, not where it is a minimum.

Comment: @martycohen His comments indicate otherwise.

Comment: That's presumably $(x+2)^2$ on the last line.